# How to show or delete li tag instead of text in input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate

I am now trying to solve some tricky javascript problem.

Here are two images that can show my dilemma.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I hope to use li tag with delete button instead of text, and if I click + button, I hope to show selectable items and if I choose some of them and click done then, show them  as li tags in input box of first image.

I don't want full source, but hope to get the directions how to handle this problem.

If you can recommend any javascript library or code to solve this issue, I will really appreciate it.

Please help me!!!

Comment: can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Now I have only idea, and hope to get direction how to solve this problem.

Comment: Now show your code html css javascript .

Comment: At least share your HTML code rathen than your images (can't see your images)

Comment: Just now, I've added html/css into jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ca77xnny/1/   Please notice it's incompleted one and need to adapt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a variation on checkboxes, isn't it?  The field is actually showing the selected boxes (`<li>`), while the dialog shows the remaining unselected ones, that a user can add?

I would do this by putting a class on those boxes indicating whether they are selected or not.  Then a simple css rule would display or hide  (`display: none` or `display: block`) based on that class.   And clicking the close box on one of the items (in the main view), or clicking the item itself (in the dialog) would toggle the selected state.

Couple of other minor notes:

- I wouldn't use 'checked' or 'selected' as your class name because of the possibility of conflicting with builtin features, or at the very least confusing people.
- If you also use `float: left` on the display the boxes should nicely fill the space compactly.
- Finally, you probably want to have *two* (duplicate) lists of items: one for the selected items in the field, and one for the unselected items in the dialog.  Both contain the complete list of possibilities, *and have the same class value* (which you have to maintain in your event handling code).  Otherwise you'd be trying to use the same DOM nodes two places in the document which would be too scary for me.

Comment: One more thing:  you won't be using the html `input` feature.  You'll make your own.  Because generally speaking the built-in input functionality is not very programmable.   You can use a _hidden input_ to pass the actual values back, if you need to.

Comment: Yeah, right. I will use div instead of input box.